# Is there a way to compose Nix Expressions for creating development environments for `nix-shell`

Tags: development-environment, code-reuse, nix

Let's say I create a Rails project and create a default.nix for a nix-shell that will create the development environment for that project via `nix-shell .`.  Naturally, this shell would have whatever dependencies I would need for Ruby on Rails.

Now let's say I also create an AngularJS project and also do the same for that, creating a `default.nix` to be run via `nix-shell .`.

Consider, in the future, I may have a project which uses both Angular and Ruby on Rails (hypothetically speaking).  Is there a way to take my Angular project's `default.nix` and my Rails project's `default.nix` and compose them together without resorting to copy-paste?

Further, let's presume that this project may later require other dependencies.  Could I maybe do something along the lines of saving the Rails `default.nix` as `rails-env.nix` and the Angular `default.nix` as `angular-env.nix`, and then include them in a new `default.nix` for my Rails-Angular + Extras project so that I can have both the dependencies declared in the `rails-env.nix` and the `angular-env.nix`, but also declare additional dependencies beyond those includes, thus maximizing the reusability of my Nix expressions for creating development environments?

Comment: Adding this comment just so that the community knows I'm still watching this question and will continue to do so until there is an answer provided.  Is there any additional information I could provide that would be helpful?

Comment: I'm having this open since it's been asked, and the answer is "yes you can", unfortunately I never find the time to write a complete answer and thus can only point you at https://nixos.org/wiki/Development_Environments and http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-arguments and give you the hint that nix expressions are functions that you can compose relatively freely.

Answer (score 1):

A Nix file is just an expression which you can import with `import ./path/to/other.nix`. You can factor out any expression you like into a separate file and reuse it. It's standard practice to make it a function so you can parametrize it differently for different projects or builds.

Here are some good examples with imports:
http://sandervanderburg.blogspot.ro/2014/07/managing-private-nix-packages-outside.html

And an intro to the Nix expression language, which is rather simple:
https://medium.com/@MrJamesFisher/nix-by-example-a0063a1a4c55

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer, but in general "link-mostly" answer are discouraged in StackOverflow, you can read more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please consider editing your answer adding a summa of the content of your links.